# merge array of different length php

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say that I have two arrays like this:

```
$arr1 = array(
array('position' => 1),
array('position' => 2),
array('position' => 3),
array('position' => 4),
array('position' => 5),
array('position' => 6),
array('position' => 7)
);

$arr2 = array(      
array(
    'a' => 'A1', 
    'b' => 'B1',
    'c' => 'C1'
),
array(
    'a' => 'A2',
    'b' => 'B2',
    'c' => 'C2'
),
array(
    'a' => 'A3',
    'b' => 'B3',
    'c' => 'C3'
)
);
```

The goal is to have a resulting array where the key `position` from the first array is copied to each array in the second array like this:

```
$final_arr = array(
array(
    'a' => 'A1',
    'b' => 'B1',
    'c' => 'C1', 
    'position' => 1
),
array(
    'a' => 'A2',
    'b' => 'B2',
    'c' => 'C2', 
    'position' => 2
),
array(
    'a' => 'A3',
    'b' => 'B3',
    'c' => 'C3', 
    'position' => 3
)
);
```

Why can't I just do this with array_merge? Any idea?

**NOTE** As you can see above, the arrays don't have the same length

Thank you for any help

Comment: foreach() loop through array2

Comment: As @Dagon suggests, iteration is the most obvious method.

Comment: What do you want to happen to $arr1 > 3?

Answer (score 2):

```
$new=array();
foreach ($arr2 as $k=>$v){

$new[]=$v+$arr1[$k];
}

print_r($new);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/tYkEWa

Comment: Can I do this with while loop?

Comment: excuse me , has been bothering you all. I have the same problem like this. I want ask when my arr2 loger then arr1 how to give a value 0 to the arr2 `position = 0` ?

Comment: @Stfvns if you have a question, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` would just join the arrays. You'd get an array made up of the values (subarrays) of `$arr1` and `$arr2`. (`array_merge` actually has two different behaviors, depending on whether the arrays it operates on have numeric keys or string/associative keys.) What you want is:

```
foreach($arr1 as $idx => $subar) {
  if (!isset($arr2[$idx])) {
    break;
  }
  $arr2[$idx]['position'] = $subar['position'];
}
```

I'm assuming the 'position' key is fixed. If it's not, then you have to guarantee that each `$subar` has a single and known key to extract using something like `array_shift(array_keys($subar))`.

Comment: your finial output does not match user765368's as you loop arr1 not arr2 (http://codepad.viper-7.com/TrsvAq)

Comment: @Dagon I copy the subarray from array 1 to the 'position' key in array 2. Since OP asked for `array_merge`, I felt updating an existing array would be more aligned with that request.

Comment: yes, but his finial array has 3 elements, not the 7 you return .. all good, up to the OP ;-)

Comment: The question seems a bit ambiguous to me. The OP is asking for a "merge" and then shows an array only containing 3 elements.